# g++ compiler is not recognizing inbuilt input() function of lex

Tags: c++, g++, bison, flex-lexer

The code is working fine with gcc compiler. But I need to use g++

```
error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
 while ((c = input()) != 0)  
                   ^
```

This error oocurs after I link it with yacc

```
static void comment(void)
{
   int c;

   while ((c = input()) != 0)
    if (c == '*')
    {
        while ((c = input()) == '*')
            ;

        if (c == '/')
            return;

        if (c == 0)
            break;
    }
  yyerror("unterminated comment");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This error oocurs after I link it with yacc"? The error occurs when you compile the flex-generated scanner; it has nothing to do with yacc/bison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to compile the flex-generated scanner with C++, then you need to use `yyinput` instead of `input`. In the scanner, the name of the function depends on whether the compiler is C or C++, allegedly to avoid a name conflict (although I don't know which version of C++ defined the name `input`):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
static int yyinput (void );
#else
static int input (void );
#endif
```

This behaviour is documented in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-input_0028_0029):

> (Note that if the scanner is compiled using C++, then `input()` is instead referred to as `yyinput()`, in order to avoid a name clash with the C++ stream by the name of `input`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to mixing C and C++. I haven't used lex in a while and don't remember if you had to declare the functions or they were provided by an include but what you should do is wrap the declaration of `input` in an `extern "C" {}` block.

Comment: If that was the problem it would show up as a linker error, not a compiler error. `error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope` means it was not declared, it doesn't mean it was declared with the wrong language linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Yacc in C mode does not declare a lot of stuff, you'll have to provide a declaration of `input()` manually.

(Hint: Try bison/flex instead and I think they support compiling with C++ compiler better)

Add:

`extern "C" int input();`

Comment: I am getting the same error  after adding extern "C" int input()  in my yacc file;

Comment: And i am using flex and bison too

Comment: Have you looked at this then? http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/03/06/flex-bison-cpp-example/

Comment: Did you add the declaration into the right section of the yacc file btw? Should be copied verbatim to top of your generated code. But better take a look at the example from the link above - it explains usage of bison with C++ a bit better.

Comment: I have done that but the problem is not in the yacc file. I am using input() function of lex in lex file itself. The error is pointed out in the lex file after linking the lex.yy.c and file.tab.c

Comment: `error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope` this is definitely NOT a linker error. you should declare `extern "C" int input();` in the lex file.